# 2D Stabilization with Autoscaling: Where can I read out the resulting resolution?

Tags: video

I am rock-solidly stabilizing a jittery movie clip and am interested to export as much from the cropped movie clip as comes out of it after Autoscaling, in whatever weird resolution that might be. (Put differently, I am not aiming for any specific output resolution, which I would scale towards in the compositor normally, before exporting)

**So where or how I can read out this information?** (e.g. something like *1234 x 987 px*)

Comment: If there is a workflow to get the video exported in the post-autoscale resolution without even having to know about this resulting resolution, that would be a valid answer for me as well, but I'd suggest posting it as a new Q&A item then, providing the answer to the rephrased question right away.

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Df3TAZ-VNso&index=4&list=PLtuvwW4VAp5tu2RdbRHThM6FVFfvFur1g
Don't you just need to disable the Autoscale option or reduce the Maximun Scale to 1.0?

Comment: I currently lack time to try this out, but feel free to confirm your idea and propose it an answer if it works! :) Thanks

Comment: It seems that with Blender 2.8 and *Autoscale* it will scale to the original resolution (the active *Viewer Node* output in *Compositing* can be seen in the *Image Editor* where the size is available in the Image properties. Without *Autoscale* (refresh the frame in *Compositing* after unchecking), the original resolution is kept, but the image stabilization causes "gaps" (unfilled areas).